# Saving $models original attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

How to change `$model`'s attributes to original. 
In my nova field file, inside fillAttributeFromRequest, if request hasSomeValue i'm looking to change my $model attributes back to original. This will mostly apply when user is editing a pre-existing resource that they have made.

```php
protected function fillAttributeFromRequest(NovaRequest $request, $requestAttribute, $model, $attribute)
{
    if ($request->hasSomeValue) 
    {
       Resource::createNew($model);
       //need to change $model back to original
    }
}
```

I have tried 
`$model->fill($model->getOriginal());`, but this throws an error, because some fields are not fillable.

I also can't do `$model->name => $model->getOriginal()->name; etc`
because it's a package and fields will be different for each user.

A working solution could be not calling the Model's `static::saving()` method, but haven't figured out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove non-fillable elements from `$originals` array ?

Like this:

```
//todo: set fillables array to public
$fillableProperties = $model->fillables; 

// filter non-fillable properties
$originalFillables = array_filter(
    $model->getOriginal(),
    function ($key) use ($fillableProperties ) {
        return in_array($key, $fillableProperties );
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);

$model->fill($originalFillables);
```

Comment: If user hasn't set fillable array inside their model, then this wont work. And since it's a package, i don't think i should require them to set fillable array.

Comment: what if you unset the $attributes elements? Or refresh() model? @Rosin

Comment: Thanks for the `refresh()` suggestion. This seems to have fixed my issue.